# Unable to Create a Splash Screen for program, Also a Color issue?

Tags: java, fonts, panel, frame, shapes

Here is my Splash code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddSplash extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
        g.drawString("Shape Stamper!", 150, 220);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        g.drawString("Programmed by: Null", 150, 245);  
    }

}
```

Here is my Main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ButtonComponent extends JComponent {

    int temp;
    Color randColor;
    Random generator = new Random();

    public ButtonComponent() {
        this.temp = temp;
        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
    }
    private ArrayList<Rectangle2D> arrOfRect = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> arrOfEllipse = new ArrayList<>();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Rectangle2D e : arrOfRect) {
            g.setColor(getRandomColor());
            g2.draw(e);
        }
        for (Ellipse2D e : arrOfEllipse) {
            g.setColor(getRandomColor());
            g2.draw(e);
        }
    }
    public void add(Point2D p) {
        double x = p.getX();
        double y = p.getY();
        if (Stamper.temp == 1) {
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            arrOfEllipse.add(ellipse);
        }
        if (Stamper.temp == 2) {
            Rectangle2D rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            arrOfRect.add(rectangle2);
        }
        if (Stamper.temp == 3) {
            Rectangle2D rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 150, 100);
            arrOfRect.add(rectangle2);
        }
        if (Stamper.temp == 4) {
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 50);
            arrOfEllipse.add(ellipse);
        }
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return new Color(generator.nextFloat(), generator.nextFloat(), generator.nextFloat());
    }
}
```

and finally the other class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stamper extends JFrame {
    public static int temp = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shape Stamper!");
        AddSplash splash = new AddSplash();

        JPanel container;
        JPanel splashtext;
        JButton circle = new JButton("Circle");
        JButton square = new JButton("Square");
        JButton rectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton oval = new JButton("Oval");

        //splashtext.add(splash);
        container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4));
        container.add(circle);
        container.add(square);
        container.add(rectangle);
        container.add(oval);


        circle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                temp = 1;
            }
        });
         square.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                temp = 2;
            }
        });
          rectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                temp = 3;
            }
        });
           oval.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                temp = 4;
            }
        });
           ButtonComponent shape = new ButtonComponent();
           frame.setSize(500, 500);

           frame.add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           frame.add(container, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

           frame.setVisible(true);
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Now for some reason i cannot retain color on the created shapes as they are created. I would like it to appear and then keep the color.
The other issue i am encountering is that I cannot get my font to appear and then be destroyed  or lose visibility upon pressing a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cannot retain color on the created shapes as they are created

You need to store the color of the shapes as well as the actual shape in your ArrayList.

See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of how this might be done.

Your code would be slightly different because you would need to create a `ColoredShape` class instead of the `ColoredRectangle` class because your code supports different types of shapes.

Comment: thats extremely helpful, any thoughts about the splash text?

Comment: @user3085119, `any thoughts about the splash text? –` - I don't see where you add the AddSplash component to the GUI. Even if you did I doubt it would display because you didn't override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a reasonable size for your panel so its size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. Why are you even doing custom painting? Just create a JPanel with a couple of JLabels to display the text.

Comment: thank you, im still grasping the basics of using graphics with java